# android record mic to ByteArray without saving audio file

Tags: android

Sorry for my bad english :(

I start my project for android application, this app record microphone, if I click to start record button the app get microphone and write it on a file and when I click to stop , a file saved into SD card.

project code :

***The output file***

```
OUTPUT_FILE = Environment.getExternalStorageState() + "/myaudio.3gp";
```

***Start recording***

```
public void startRecord() throws IOException{
    if (recorder != null)
    {
        recorder.release();
    }
    File outFile = new File(OUTPUT_FILE);
    if (outFile.exists())
    {
        outFile.delete();
    }

    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile(OUTPUT_FILE);
    recorder.prepare();
    recorder.start();
}
```

***Stop recording***

```
public void stopRec(){
    recorder.stop();
}
```

***PlaySound recorded file***

```
public void playRecFile() throws IOException{
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(OUTPUT_FILE);
    mediaPlayer.prepare();
    mediaPlayer.start();

}
```

I want to get recorded voice and put it into a variable ByteArray and play it whitout saving the audio file to SD card

I have a project like what I want but it is written in actionscript 3

```
import flash.media.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;

var ch:SoundChannel
var mic:Microphone = Microphone.getMicrophone();

mic.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, micSampleDataHandler);
mic.addEventListener(ActivityEvent.ACTIVITY,onAct);

function onAct(evt:ActivityEvent):void
{
    trace(evt.activating,mic.activityLevel);
    if (!evt.activating)
    {
        if (soundBytes.length)
        {
            timerHandler();
        }
    }
}

var soundBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
var soundO:ByteArray = new ByteArray();

function micSampleDataHandler(event:SampleDataEvent):void
{
    trace(event.data.length,event.data.bytesAvailable, soundBytes.length);
    while (event.data.bytesAvailable)
    {
        var sample:Number = event.data.readFloat();
        soundBytes.writeFloat(sample);
    }
}

function timerHandler():void
{
    mic.removeEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, micSampleDataHandler);
    soundBytes.position = 0;
    soundO.writeBytes(soundBytes);
    soundO.position = 0;
    soundBytes.position = 0;
    soundBytes.length=0;

    var sound:Sound= new Sound();
    sound.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, playbackSampleHandler);
    ch=sound.play();
    ch.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE,onSC)
    trace("OUTPUT",soundO.bytesAvailable);

}
function onSC(evt:Event):void
{
    trace("SOUND_COMPLETE");
}
function playbackSampleHandler(event:SampleDataEvent):void
{
    trace("SAMPLE_DATA: ",soundO.bytesAvailable)
    for (var i:int = 0; i < 8192; i++)
    {
        if (soundO.bytesAvailable < 4)
        {
         break;
        }
        var sample:Number = soundO.readFloat();
        event.data.writeFloat(sample);
        event.data.writeFloat(sample);      
    }
    if (soundO.bytesAvailable < 4 && soundO.position!==0)
    {
        mic.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, micSampleDataHandler);
        soundO.position=0
        soundO.length = 0;

        trace("END
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you have a mistake: replace `Environment.getExternalStorageState()` to `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` in your OUTPUT_FILE name.

Answer (score 9):

## **Check Out this answer! It works exactly with `MediaRecorder` not `AudioRecord`**

Try to use the following solution to record audio to byte array using `MediaRecorder`:

```
    // Byte array for audio record
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    ParcelFileDescriptor[] descriptors = ParcelFileDescriptor.createPipe();
    ParcelFileDescriptor parcelRead = new ParcelFileDescriptor(descriptors[0]);
    ParcelFileDescriptor parcelWrite = new ParcelFileDescriptor(descriptors[1]);

    InputStream inputStream = new ParcelFileDescriptor.AutoCloseInputStream(parcelRead);

    MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile(parcelWrite.getFileDescriptor());
    recorder.prepare();

    recorder.start();


    int read;
    byte[] data = new byte[16384];

    while ((read = inputStream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
        byteArrayOutputStream.write(data, 0, read);
    }

    byteArrayOutputStream.flush();
```

I wrap this code in `AsyncTask` for start execution.

Also, don't forgot to run the following code to stop recording:

```
    recorder.stop();
    recorder.reset();
    recorder.release();
```

To convert `byteArrayOutputStream` to `byte[]` use `byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()`

Comment: Hi,I used your code it converts byte array from coming mic audio and I was write aac file formar but When I played aac format it gives error,it cannot play.                                                 while ((read = inputStream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(data, 0, read);
            byte[] ses_data = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

            writeToFile(ses_data,"/mnt/sdcard2/rota/byte.aac");
        }

Answer (score 4):

Use the following class to get the Recorded Mic data As the Byte Array. You will get the data as buffer.. try to use that.. hope this will helps you ..

```
class AudioRecordThread implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int bufferLength = 0;
            int bufferSize;
            short[] audioData;
            int bufferReadResult;

            try {
                bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleAudioBitRate, 
                        AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

                if (bufferSize <= 2048) {
                    bufferLength = 2048;
                } else if (bufferSize <= 4096) {
                    bufferLength = 4096;
                }

                /* set audio recorder parameters, and start recording */
                audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, sampleAudioBitRate, 
                        AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferLength);
                audioData = new short[bufferLength];
                audioRecord.startRecording();
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "audioRecord.startRecording()");

                isAudioRecording = true;

                /* ffmpeg_audio encoding loop */
                while (isAudioRecording) {
                    bufferReadResult = audioRecord.read(audioData, 0, audioData.length);

                    if (bufferReadResult == 1024 && isRecorderStart) {
                        Buffer realAudioData1024 = ShortBuffer.wrap(audioData,0,1024);

                    *********************************** 
                        recorder.record(realAudioData1024);
                        ***********************************

                    } else if (bufferReadResult == 2048 && isRecorderStart) {
                        Buffer realAudioData2048_1=ShortBuffer.wrap(audioData, 0, 1024);
                        Buffer realAudioData2048_2=ShortBuffer.wrap(audioData, 1024, 1024);
                        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                            if (i == 0) {
        ***********************************                     
        recorder.record(realAudioData2048_1);
        ***********************************                      

                            } else if (i == 1) {
***********************************
recorder.record(realAudioData2048_2);
***********************************


                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                /* encoding finish, release recorder */
                if (audioRecord != null) {
                    try {
                        audioRecord.stop();
                        audioRecord.release();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    audioRecord = null;
                }

                if (recorder != null && isRecorderStart) {
                    try {
                        recorder.stop();
                        recorder.release();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    recorder = null;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "get audio data failed:"+e.getMessage()+e.getCause()+e.toString());
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you have a for loop?(I'm talking about the one comes after readlAudioData2048_2)

Answer (score 3):

**I want to get recorded voice and put it into a variable ByteArray and play it whitout saving the audio file to SD card**

Use the [AudioRecord](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html) class to grab audio from the mic into an array and then feed it into an [AudioTrack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html).

Comment: See Rajesh's answer for how to set up and use an AudioRecord. The process is very similar for AudioTrack. I'm sure you can find examples if you look around here at stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr Michael