# How I can start the android mediarecorder without saving the recording to a file?

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, android-mediarecorder

When you use the android mediarecorder you have to first prepare it and then you can start it. While preparing you also **have** to set an outputfile.

Once you start the mediarecorder by calling `mMediaRecorder.start()`, you get the camera preview running.
When you call `mMediaRecorder.stop()`, the recording stops but the camera preview continues showing the preview.

Now, what I would like to be able to do is start the camera preview of the mediarecorder but not start the recording. Just show the preview.

How can I do that?

What I am doing right now is starting the mediarecorder, then immediately stop it and then delete the outputfile. However, this is a very nasty workaround...

Comment: Why not just open the camera, give it a SurfaceHolder, and call startPreview() as described at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html ?

Comment: What platform version are you targeting?  For API 18+, see "Show + capture camera" in https://github.com/google/grafika .

Comment: Check out this related solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13974234/android-record-mic-to-bytearray-without-saving-audio-file/42750515#42750515

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to prepare the recorder (or *any* part of the `MediaRecorder` itself) to get a preview. The preview is handled by the `Camera`, not the `MediaRecorder`. The [developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#capture-video) shows these steps to capture video:

1. Open Camera
2. Connect Preview
3. Start Preview
4. *Start Recording Video*
5. *Stop Recording Video*
6. Stop Preview
7. Release Camera

Notice that starting the preview comes *before* starting the recording. If all you wanted to do was show a preview, you could omit steps four and five altogether.

Of course, the sample *code* in the developer guide kinda glosses over that. You can find a pretty good example of this [here](http://www.integratingstuff.com/2010/10/18/writing-code-that-captures-videos-on-android/). The code there is targeted at 2.2, but it should work with no/minor changes on newer platforms.