# Record Video To Byte Array Without Writing To File

Tags: android, video, camera, arrays, mediarecorder

I'm implementing a custom video camera using the [Google Developer API Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera); it uses the [`MediaRecorder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html) class to create and manage all the settings/operations of the video camera.

Save for the fact that it's taking way too long to write the file to the phone (after recording, it'll be about 5 minutes before I even get to see the file under *Gallery*), it's working as it should.

But I don't want a file: **I need the raw byte array** the recording produces, before it's dumped into a file.

Does [`MediaRecorder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html) even allow you to do this? Am I in the right direction?

A good example of what I need is how the `PictureCallback`'s [`onPictureTaken()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PictureCallback.html) method gives you a byte array which contains the picture in bytes.

Comment: I do not know of a raw video codec that Android supports. Most codecs, like MP4, will cause the recorder to want to rewrite the file header. You are welcome to stitch together a video from those preview frames, as Vine does.

Comment: Ok, so how would I go about doing that?

Comment: I assume they are using `ffmpeg` or something along those lines to create a video out of frames. There's a conference video where a Vine engineer explains the problems they encountered using `MediaRecorder` and how they wound up using preview callback frames, though I don't have a link to it and I don't recall them going into low-level details of their solution.

Comment: Any idea on why saving the video is taking so long?

Comment: Check out this related solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13974234/android-record-mic-to-bytearray-without-saving-audio-file/42750515#42750515

Answer (score 3):

`MediaRecorder` is intended to be simple: tell it where the inputs come from, give it a file to write to, and let it run.

If you want something more flexible, you need to use `MediaCodec`.  The set of features you want doesn't really exist until API 18 (Android 4.3).

[Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika) includes the "Continuous capture" activity, which records H.264 video to a circular buffer in memory, and writes the current set of frames to a file when you hit "Capture".  This is video-only; if you want audio, you'd need to deal with that separately.

For earlier versions of Android you'd need to use a 3rd-party library like ffmpeg to handle the video encoding, which will reduce your frame rate significantly.

Answer (score 1):

> after recording, it'll be about 5 minutes before I even get to see the file under Gallery

That's probably because you didn't do anything to make it show up in the Gallery faster, such as use `MediaScannerConnection` and `scanFile()`. The Gallery doesn't find out files until either you tell it about the file or it comes up in a periodic scan.

Comment: Do You suggest any solution to the Above Question ? I have been stuck in the same problem aswell.